# DataGridView set different font size within same cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In a standard winforms DataGridView cell, is it possible to set more than one font size within a single cell?

For example, if I add 3 columns to a `DataTable`

```
int item1 = someVal;
int item2 = someOtherVal;
string item3 = Sum[i] + Environment.NewLine + Count[i]
dataTable.Rows.Add(item1, item2, item3)
```

then I can wrap the third column string to look like the following in a single cell....

```
 Sum[i]
Count[i]
```

by setting the following on the DataGridView column

```
columnx.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
columnx.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

How can I then show `Sum[i]` as one font size and `Count[i]` as another font size within the same DataGridView cell?

Comment: I've not been able to personally test this at home due to the required VS version, but [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView) article about creating a RichTextBox cell/column *might* be a starting point.  I'd be interested to hear if it works.

Comment: You need to code the CellPainting event. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228710/how-can-i-create-a-footer-for-cell-in-datagridview/30234696#30234696) for an example