# How can I create a footer for cell in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, cell

I need to create a DataGridView with cells that have two parts. One part is the content of that cell such as 0, 1 etc value. And the remain part is the footer of that cell, just like a footer of a word document, refers to the ordinal number of that cell.

I can not enclose any images so the question may be ambiguous.

Anyways thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: use listview insteed. otherwise you have to customize datagridview and add footer functionary which you can take copy from listview.

Comment: Did you have a look at my answer ad does it look like what you want to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

To create `DataGridView` cells with extra content you need to code the `CellPainting` event.

First you set up the cells to have enough room for the extra content and layout the normal content as you wish..:

```
DataGridView DGV = dataGridView1;  // quick reference

Font fatFont = new Font("Arial Black", 22f);
DGV .DefaultCellStyle.Font = fatFont;
DGV .RowTemplate.Height = 70;
DGV .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter;
```

Next I fill in some content; I add the extra content to the cells' `Tags`. For more complicated things with more fonts etc, you will want to create a class or stucture to hold it, maybe also in the `Tags`..

```
DGV.Rows.Clear();
DGV.Rows.Add(3);

DGV[1, 0].Value = "Na"; DGV[1, 0].Tag = "Natrium";
DGV[1, 1].Value = "Fe"; DGV[1, 1].Tag = "Ferrum";
DGV[1, 2].Value = "Au"; DGV[1, 2].Tag = "Aurum";
```

Here is an example of coding the `CellPainting` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, 
               DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0) return;  // header? nothing to do!
    if (e.ColumnIndex == yourAnnotatedColumnIndex )
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
        string footnote = "";
        if (cell.Tag != null) footnote = cell.Tag.ToString();

        int y = e.CellBounds.Bottom - 15;  // pick your  font height

        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true); // show selection? why not..
        e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);          // normal content
        using (Font smallFont = new Font("Times", 8f))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(footnote, smallFont,
              cell.Selected ? Brushes.White : Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds.Left, y);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

For longer multiline footnotes you can use a bounding `Rectangle` instead of just the x&y coordinates..

Comment: Solid answer to an otherwise ambiguous question.  Nice job

Comment: Thank you TaW I got it. Sorry for not replying I am so busy recently.

Comment: Is `DataGridView DGV = dataGridView2;` supposed to be 2 or 1? Thank you.

Comment: This answer is simply wonderful. Also, what is the point of the `e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);`? When I remove it I get the same results.

Comment: Could it be that you do not have any 'normal' content?